# AppDelegate valueForUndefinedKey

Tags: ios, swift, service, delegates, appdelegate

I am making an app in swift but I am facing some problems. I am trying to run my app but I get an error every time.

This is the full error :
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[ valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key currentUnityController.'

In the AppDelegate I use services like this:

```
@UIApplicationMain
final class AppDelegate: AppwiseCore.AppDelegate<Config> {
override var services: [ApplicationService] {
    return [
        UnityApplicationService(),
        FabricApplicationService(),
        KeyboardManagerApplicationService()
    ]
}
}
```

Then I call the UnityAppcontroller like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?

var application: UIApplication?
@objc var currentUnityController: UnityAppController!
var isUnityRunning = false

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.application = application
    unity_init(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
    currentUnityController = UnityAppController()
    currentUnityController.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    startUnity()
    return true
}
```

And finally this is how I acces the app controller.

```
NS_INLINE UnityAppController* GetAppController()
{
NSObject<UIApplicationDelegate>* delegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UnityAppController* currentUnityController = (UnityAppController*)[delegate valueForKey: @"currentUnityController"];
return currentUnityController;
```

}

Anny Help?

Comment: Why not just cast `delegate` to `AppDelegate` and then use it's property `currentUnityController `?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a control in your nib (xib file) that is linked to a property (IBOutlet) or method (IBAction) in your view controller, and you have either deleted or renamed the property or method, the runtime can't find it because it has been renamed and therefore crashes.